# Lenovo X1 Carbon 2015 only boots on second attempt on 15.04 - but always fails on first boot

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, lenovo

After Kernel upgrade last week my lenovo x1 carbon 2015 fails to boot on first attempt (with nice graphics). It is configured with full disk encryption so I usually see a nice ubuntu screen with passphrase input.

Since last week I see just a black screen. When I switch to console with Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2.. I see mysterious thick white lines in the upper left corner.

When I power off and reboot I can then boot into ubuntu with a "failsafe" mode as it does not show nice graphics but just plain text to enter my passphrase. After this everything runs fine as usual.

I think it must be a graphics driver which doe not work and fails.

```
# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
# lshw -c video
  *-display               
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
       Version: 09
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       Konfiguration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       Ressourcen: irq:48 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(Größe=64)
# uname -a
Linux thinkpad 3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 20:58:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am runnng ubuntu 15.04

How can I fix this problem?